# Translating armv7m instructions to llvm IR

Tags: c++, binary, llvm, lifting

**I am building a lifter that lifts from armv7m instructions to llvm IR.
so I am trying to translate all armv7m instructions to their equivalent llvm instructions.
I am new to llvm and I wanted to create and print an llvm instruction. So just starting with a simple add instruction my code is:**

```
            llvm::LLVMContext TheContext;

            llvm::IRBuilder<> Builder(TheContext);  

            auto* L = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext), 41);

            auto* R = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext), 42);       

            llvm::Value* Add=Builder.CreateAdd(L, R, "addtmp");             

            Add->print(llvm::errs());
```

**The output I want is**

```
%addtmp = add i32 41, i32 42;
```

**The output I get is**

```
i32 83
```

**First point, How can I display the instruction without being evaluated, please?.**

**Second point. As you can see in the above code**

```
auto* L = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext), 41);

auto* R = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext), 42);
```

**I am creating two constant ints as operands for my add instruction, now how can I create an operand to the add instruction that isn't an int ..just a variable. A place holder you might say.
For example the x and the y variables here.**

```
 %tmp = add i32 %x, %y
```

Comment: The evaluation you mention is called constant folding, and it's done by the builder. You can just create the instruction yourself instead using [BinaryOperator::Create()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html#aa6655ccc115ddade69c02b6dcc30c5fe), IMO it's as easy to use the *::Create() functions as the builder. As for the placeholders... I think the general answer is that compilers tend to generate IR only when they hav the operands. For various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you received an `i32 83` instead of an add instruction is that the default FolderTy template argument for the `llvm::IRBuilder` is `llvm::ConstantFolder`.

https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1IRBuilder.html

```cpp
template <typename FolderTy = ConstantFolder,
          typename InserterTy = IRBuilderDefaultInserter>
class IRBuilder : public IRBuilderBase {
```

To combat this issue you can use `llvm::NoFolder` which does not perform constant folding. https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1NoFolder.html#details